# How do I correct SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE statement?

Tags: mysql, excel

I have a VBA code that uses the `DELETE FROM` and `INSERT INTO` statement to export data from an excel table to mySQL which is giving me a Run Time Error

[image]

I am not sure why its giving me error, is there something I am missing as to why its not working

The problem seems to be at

```
 sSQL = " INSERT INTO feed SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" _
       & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[Feed$A1:G" & height & "]"
```

Here is all the details about the workbook

The sheet name is "Feed"

the table name in MySQL is "feed"

the file path to the file is C:\Users\silva_000\Desktop\Apps\Vba Integrate.xlsm

Here is the full code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "DATABASE=engine;" & _
        "USER=root;" & _
        "PASSWORD=;" & _
        "Option=3"
    
    'number of rows with records. testingupload is the sheetname.
    Dim height As Integer
    height = Worksheets("Feed").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim sSQL As String
    sSQL = "DELETE FROM feed"
    Cn.Execute sSQL

  sSQL = " INSERT INTO feed SELECT * FROM [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" _
       & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "].[Feed$A1:G" & height & "]"
    
    Cn.Execute sSQL
    
    Cn.Close
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot use such datasource specification in MySQL query.

Comment: Sure , please help me on which specifications are needed to make the code work? I am still amateur, sometimes it's too complex for me  I guess

Comment: MySQL cannot access Excel datasource. Save your Excel dataset as CSV to the location local for MySQL then import the data using LOAD DATA. Or insert row-by-row.